# Android; start and stop openGL animation from a normal Activity

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

I am trying to develop an app which should do many things besides starting an animation (using openGL rendering) and then stopping it after 10 seconds or so (and returning back to the activity screen).

I have developed the activity class and the openGL rendering separately.
But not sure how to put them together and start and stop the openGL animation when I want.

I am a complete newbie to Android. Any suggestions, help, pointers to examples will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One moves between `Activity`s in android with `Intent`s. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: intents.. looks like what I wanted. Thank sastraxi!

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use some OGL engine if you start from scratch. There are a few ones exists, e.g. [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/).
It is fast and easy to use open source OpenGL engine with Java frontend. It has lack of documentation but has **huge** friendly community. Take a look at forum for good tutorials, examples, FAQs and support. I use it for my indie games.

Comment: Thanks for the reply asktomsk. Actually I am not developing a game, but my app just tries to read the fps supported by the device. For example, my app activity will have a button and when I press it, it should run the opengl animation for 10s or so and then return the fps calculated. This is where I am stuck.